# How can I stop input from registering inside my game when I am dragging status bar from the top?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Basically on newer phones such as the ones with the notch at the top I have been able to play games where I swipe the top of my screen to access the status bar without any input impacting my game.

Games such as [Circle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ketchapp.circle&hl=en) and [Jelly Jump](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ketchapp.jellyjump&hl=en)) are examples that do this.

I basically want a similar sort of thing. Right now when I drag down my status bar from the top, my game ends up activating which is something I don't want.

My code to start the game is upon a very simple mouse down input which also registers as a touch on phones:

```
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Jump();
    }
```

An example of what I want can be shown via this diagram I've
 [drawn here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b90ns.png).

Answer (score 0):

You could have an invisible UI panel in that area and then check using `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()` to check if the click/touch is over an UI element. Not that for touch, the function is `IsPointerOverGameObject(touchID)`. Also you will need a graphic raycaster attached to the canvas.

Another option would be to check the x/y value (depending on orientation) of the touch position and to only register input if it's above a certain value.

`if(Input.GetTouch(0).position.x < 20) return`